# Replay an Http.Request in Play! Framework

Tags: java, playframework

Is there a possibility in [Play! Framework](https://www.playframework.com/) to "replay" a `Http.Request`? Replay in the sense of re-applying the request as if it was received again.

**Context Information**
In my specific use-case I'm trying to resolve an issue where a POST request (eg. a form submission) is rejected if the user's session is no longer valid. Responding to the POST request with a redirect to the login page will result in the POST data being lost. Which is obviously bad from the end-users perspective.

My current idea is to store the original `Http.Request` object in a HashMap (or any other kind of store) and then respond with a redirect to the login page. After the user has logged in again, the previously stored request should be replayed as if the user would have re-submitted the form, and the `Result` of this replay can then be returned back directly to the user.

The first part works fine, storing the original POST `Http.Request` in a HashMap and then flagging the user's session so the original request can later be retrieved again. After the user has logged in, I can retrieve the original POST request, but I'm unsure if and how it is possible to replay this request now. I could probably convert the `Http.Request` to a `WSRequest` and send it from the backend to itself with a `WSClient`, but this seems a bit hacky, and there probably is a simpler solution.

The code below is just for showcasing an example and is not actual source code. Please ignore the obvious issues it has. My question concerns the part marked with `TODO`.

```java
public class DummyController extends Controller {

    private final FormFactory formFactory;
    private final HashMap<UUID, Http.Request> rejectedRequests;

    @Inject
    public DummyController(FormFactory formFactory) {
        this.formFactory = formFactory;
        this.rejectedRequests = new HashMap<>();
    }

    // GET endpoint for the login form
    public Result login() {
        return ok("render login form");
    }

    // POST endpoint for the login form submission
    public Result loginPost(Http.Request request) {
        Form<LoginForm> form = formFactory.form(LoginForm.class).bindFromRequest(request);
        if (form.hasErrors()) {
            return badRequest("wrong credentials");
        } else {
            return request.session().get("original-req")
                    .map(UUID::fromString)
                    .map(rejectedRequests::get)
                    .map(originalRequest -> {
                        // TODO: how to replay the original request here?
                        return TODO(request).removingFromSession(request, "original-req");
                    })
                    .orElseGet(() -> redirect("/"));
        }
    }

    // POST endpoint for some form submission
    public Result formSubmit(Http.Request request) {
        if (request.session().get("login").isPresent()) {
            final UUID key = UUID.randomUUID();
            rejectedRequests.put(key, request);
            return redirect("/login").addingToSession(request, "original-req", key.toString());
        }
        return ok("handle form submit");
    }

}
```

Comment: Well these are plain regular methods, you can call `formSubmit` from another method. Not sure replaying the actual instance of `Request` is the best approach though, I would rather store/retrieve only the data it contains.

Comment: I agree that this would potentially be the cleaner approach. However, the point is that I need the request to go through the Filters and Actions again, because there are important checks every request must go through (the redirect for invalid/expired sessions happens inside one of them).

Comment: Okay, then you need an actual HTTP request indeed